# Disposeパターンの「大きなフィールドを null に設定します」の意味

Tags: c#

Visual Studio の補助機能で破棄パターンを実装したとき、「TODO: 大きなフィールドを null に設定します」とのコメントが生成されるのですが、この意味がわかりません。このインスタンスが破棄されるときはフィールドもいっしょに破棄されるはずなので、あえて null を設定する必要性がないように思えます。これには意味があるのでしょうか？それとも別の意味なのでしょうか？

以下、実装例です。`_buffer = null` の効果が疑問です。

```cs
    public class Sample : IDisposable
    {
        private byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        private bool _disposedValue;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // TODO: マネージド状態を破棄します (マネージド オブジェクト)
                }

                // TODO: アンマネージド リソース (アンマネージド オブジェクト) を解放し、ファイナライザーをオーバーライドします
                // TODO: 大きなフィールドを null に設定します
                _buffer = null; // ← ???

                _disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        ~Sample()
        {
            Dispose(disposing: false);
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「TODO: 大きなフィールドを null に設定します」とのコメントが生成されるのですが、この意味がわかりません。

Microsoft のドキュメントには説明は見つけられませんが、以下の Stackoverflow 本家の記事の回答の通りだと思います。

Why does Visual Studio suggest "TODO: set large fields to null."?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729785/why-does-visual-studio-suggest-todo-set-large-fields-to-null

関係ある回答の一部を以下に抜粋しておきます。

The "set large fields to null" advice also thoroughly falls in the "not wrong" category. It will not often make any difference, it is however technically possible that the "large object" lives in an earlier GC generation. Which is somewhat likely to happen when it was allocated late, long after the disposable object was created. Setting it to Nothing then allows the GC to release it earlier and the program will run leaner. Nothing wrong with that.

要するに、「特に効果はないかもしれないが念のためやっておいても悪くはない」と言っています。

ちなみにですが、質問のコードの Sample クラスでは Dispose パターンを実装しても意味がありません。

自分で作るカスタムクラスの場合、マネージドリソースしか保持しない場合は Dispose パターンの実装は不要です。必要なのはアンマネージドリソースを保持する場合のみですが、それには以下のケースがあると思います。

(1) Dispose パターンを実装した .NET のクラスのインスタンスを保持している。

(2) クラス内でアンマネージドリソースを取得し、それを保持している。

Sample クラスはそのどちらにも該当しません。

自分のブログで恐縮ですが、もう少し詳しい説明を以下の記事に書きましたので、興味があれば見てください。

Dispose パターン
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2019/05/31/dispose-pattern.aspx

Comment: 特殊なパターンにおいて大きなフィールドをnullにすることでGC回収が早くなる、かもしれない、ぐらいの意味で、必須ではないようですね。「TODO」を「すべきこと」と思っていたのが悩みを深めてしまっていたようです。

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable`による破棄パターンは、

- リソースの破棄
- GC解放

を分離します。つまり、`Dispose`メソッドによりリソースは破棄されたものの、GC上はまだインスタンスが生きています。
「大きなフィールドを null に設定」することにより、`Dispose`のタイミングで不要になった大きなフィールドをGC解放できるメリットがあります。

---

> ファイナライザーから呼ばれるアンマネージド破棄処理に実装していることが疑問

こちら、`Dispose`メソッドが呼ばれなかった場合でも多少ながら価値があります。
ファイナライザーが実装されているオブジェクトについては、次のステップとなります。

1. GCが参照カウント0を検出しインスタンスを破棄しようとする。ファイナライザーが実装されている場合、破棄を見送り、ファイナライザースレッドに送る。
2. ファイナライザースレッド上でファイナライザーを実行する。
3. 再度、GCが参照カウント0を検出しインスタンスを破棄しようとする。今度はファイナライザー実行完了済みなので、インスタンスを破棄する。

ですので、

- 「大きなフィールドを null に設定」してあれば

  - `Dispose`メソッドが呼ばれたタイミングで大きなフィールドが解放される
  - `Dispose`メソッドを呼ばなかった場合はファイナライザー実行のタイミングで大きなフィールドが解放される
- 「大きなフィールドを null に設定」してなければ

  - GC解放されるまで大きなフィールドが維持される

となります。

Comment: Dispose() 実行時の処理であれば `if (disposing)` スコープのマネージドオブジェクト破棄処理で実装すれば良さそうですが、ファイナライザーから呼ばれるアンマネージド破棄処理に実装していることが疑問です。

Comment: ファイナライザーの実装の有無によって挙動が変わってくるのですね。なるほどです。